# Selenium driver failing with Opera 87.0.4390.45

Tags: selenium-webdriver, opera

I’m using the driver at https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases/tag/v.99.0.4844.51

for my opera browser, with version **87.0.4390.45**

I have a **Maven-3.6.3** + **Java-14** application, when I try to instance an opera driver, It appears an instant window, which hides right after.

Windows 11 Home machine.

Piece of Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
...
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
...
```

Maven library:

**org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.4**

I believe this is failing because of any browser update. It was working a month ago with version **4.1.3**.
I just upgraded trying to solve this.

log:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. session not created: This version of OperaDriver only supports Opera version 99
>
> Current browser version is 101.0.4951.67 with binary path C:\Users\nesto\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\87.0.4390.45\opera.exe(Driver info: operadriver=99.0.4844.51 (d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.22000 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Any tip will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I know Opera can not meet requirements of Selenium 4 infrastructure (W3C standards) so Opera Driver is deprecated in Selenium 4 version. Read below topics for more information:

[Opera webdriver is not starting on Selenium 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560244/opera-webdriver-is-not-starting-on-selenium-4)