# Opera webdriver is not starting on Selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-python

I am trying to run the webdriver for opera browser under selenium 4. I am using webdriver-manager in my project. The webdriver-manager docs suggest using webdriver.Opera:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('allow-elevated-browser')
options.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\FOLDERLOCATION\\Opera\\VERSION\\opera.exe"
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

In this case browser doesn't even open and crashes with a SessionNotCreatedException.

However the selenium docs suggest using webdriver.Chrome():

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
return webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(OperaDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

And this also doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to run Opera on selenium 4?

Update. Added stack trace

```
test setup failed
request = <SubRequest 'browser' for <Function test_go_to[opera]>>

    @pytest.fixture(params=["opera"])
    def browser(request):
        browser_name = request.param
        browser = Browser.get_browser()
>       browser.set_up_driver(browser_name=browser_name)

..\..\conftest.py:28: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\web\browser\browser.py:34: in set_up_driver
    self.__web_driver[browser_name] = BrowserFactory.get_browser_driver(browser_name)
..\web\browser\browser_factory.py:41: in get_browser_driver
    return webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install(), options=options)
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\opera\webdriver.py:75: in __init__
    OperaDriver.__init__(self, executable_path=executable_path,
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\opera\webdriver.py:51: in __init__
    ChromiumDriver.__init__(self,
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:70: in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:92: in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:275: in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:365: in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:430: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x0000023F2D81A4D0>
response = {'sessionId': 'dcd7a5f2e8dd69e636f110a8ed51220d', 'status': 33, 'value': {'message': 'session not created: Missing or ...5.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)'}}

    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """
        Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.
    
        :Args:
         - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
           object.
    
        :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
        """
        status = response.get('status', None)
        if not status or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen: str = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get('value', None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, str):
                import json
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                        value = value['value']
                    status = value.get('error', None)
                    if not status:
                        status = value.get("status", ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
                        message = value.get("value") or value.get("message")
                        if not isinstance(message, str):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get('message')
                    else:
                        message = value.get('message', None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    
        exception_class: Type[WebDriverException]
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_SHADOW_ROOT:
            exception_class = NoSuchShadowRootException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
            exception_class = JavascriptException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
            exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
            exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
            exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
            exception_class = ScreenshotException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
            exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
            exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
            exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
            exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
            exception_class = UnknownMethodException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if not value:
            value = response['value']
        if isinstance(value, str):
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and 'message' in value:
            message = value['message']
    
        screen = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
        if 'screen' in value:
            screen = value['screen']
    
        stacktrace = None
        st_value = value.get('stackTrace') or value.get('stacktrace')
        if st_value:
            if isinstance(st_value, str):
                stacktrace = st_value.split('\n')
            else:
                stacktrace = []
                try:
                    for frame in st_value:
                        line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                        file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                        if line:
                            file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                        meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                        if 'className' in frame:
                            meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                        msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                        msg = msg % (meth, file)
                        stacktrace.append(msg)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
        if exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if 'data' in value:
                alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
            elif 'alert' in value:
                alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities
E         (Driver info: operadriver=102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)

..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:247: SessionNotCreatedException
```

My current version of code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('allow-elevated-browser')
options.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera\\opera.exe"
webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Comment: How are you calling it?  -did you update the filepath?  ->  `options.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\FOLDERLOCATION\\Opera\\VERSION\\opera.exe"`?    There's limited value giving us code from the docs. It's better if you show your code...... 
   additionally, can you please share the full error after `SessionNotCreatedException`  - normally errors tell you why it failed

Comment: Yes, I have updated the path. Also added a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these discussions, opera does not support the w3c standard, and therefore has problems with selenium 4. https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/100
https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/96

The solution was to set the option w3c to True

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('allow-elevated-browser')
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', True)
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```